# Javascript memory heap size keeps on increasing when navigating from page to page. How to identify the memory leak?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I am running a React + Next.js e-commerce website with MongoDB database and mongoose driver. When using the Chrome browser memory profiler, the initial memory heap size when the app is just started is around 30 MB.

[image: Screenshot of initial heap snapshot]

If I interact with the website sitting in only one page, the memory heap doesn't increase much. However, when navigating to other pages, for example, moving to the all products page and scrolling down and loading more products with infinite scrolling, the memory heap size increases rapidly. In the screenshot below, it can be seen that between the comparison of snapshot 3 & 4, the heap size increased by 30 MB when navigating to other pages, loading products and viewing them.

[image: Screenshot of heap snapshot comparison]

I am running these tests on production mode in my local computer. In my VPS where the website is deployed live, the amount of RAM consumed by the node process running my website also seems to increase over time. Here is a screenshot of my top command results. The second process with PID 1159 is the one that's running the website. Currently the %MEM column shows it is using 4.9% of the memory but over the day it goes over 7% until I restart the app and the memory usage comes down.

[image: Ubuntu VPS memory usage by top command]

I am guessing there's a memory leak but not being able to figure out what's causing it.

Some things that I doubt are unusual:

- When navigating to all products page and infinitely scrolling to load more products, that is when the memory heap increases dramatically. After navigating away from that page, there seems to be a lot of detached HTML elements that doesn't seem to be garbage collected. Here is a screenshot of the memory profiler. [image]
- In the heap snapshot summary inside the system / JSArrayBufferData tree, there is an object named mongoose in Window that shows a high percentage in the Retained Size Column. Why is mongoose loaded into Window? [image: Heap Snapshot summary]

All these are concerning because my VPS has been performing poorly and I suspect high memory usage is the cause.

Some extra information for purpose of debugging:

I am establishing connection to the mongodb database using the following middleware:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const connectDB = handler => async (req, res) => {
if (mongoose.connections[0].readyState) {
return handler(req, res);
}
await mongoose.connect(`MONGODB_URI`, {
useUnifiedTopology: true,
useNewUrlParser: true
});
return handler(req,res);
};
export default connectDB
```

I am exporting mongoose Schemas in the following way:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    section: String,
    category: String,
    category_slug: String,
    sub_category: String,
    sub_category_slug: String,
    product_code: String,
    title: String,
    description: String,
    batch_number: String,
    tags: [],
    warranty: String,
    similar_products: [{label: String, value: String, _id: false}],
    compatibility: {
        make_and_model: [],
        year: [],
        engine_chasis: []
    },
    product_variants: [{ type: new mongoose.Schema(
        {
        variant_code: String,
        variant_title: String,
        slug: String,
        color_variant: Boolean,
        images: [{id: Number, name: String}],
        status: String,
        views: Number,
        variant_details: [{ type: new mongoose.Schema(
            {
                size: String,
                local_price: { type: Number, default: 0 },
                local_discount: { type: Number, default: 0 },
                inventory: [{
                    type: new mongoose.Schema(
                        {
                            branch_id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, quantity: Number
                        }
                    )
                }]
            }
        )
        }]
        }
    ) 
    }]
}, {timestamps: true})


mongoose.models = {};

export default mongoose.models.Product || mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);
```

I am willing to provide more information if needed for debugging purpose. Any solutions and feedback are highly appreciated.

Comment: You realise your browser's memory has nothing to do with VPS' memory, right?

Comment: @AlexBlex, I wasn't aware of that. I thought since there is a probable memory leak in the client side, it was affecting server side performance as well. However, I'd still like to solve the memory leak issue.

Comment: @Yogiraj , unfortunately I still haven't found a solution.